# Update a column in MySQL table if only the values are empty or NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, joomla

I had previously applied this query...which works perfectly and was answered by one of the fellow members of this forum

```
UPDATE
    jos_jbjobs_jobseeker a
    INNER JOIN jos_users b ON a.email = b.email
SET
    a.user_id = b.id
```

Now i want to use the same query adding one more condition... i.e

Set a.user_id = b.id only if a.user_id is empty ,,

can i apply this :

> if a.user_id = ''  SET  a.user_id = b.id ;

?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
UPDATE
    jos_jbjobs_jobseeker a
    INNER JOIN jos_users b ON a.email = b.email
SET
    a.user_id = b.id
WHERE a.id IS NULL OR LENGTH(a.id)=0;
```

Comment: ok so basically this was important ...LENGTH(b.id)=0;  Thanks

Comment: it worked but out of curiosity..Whats the difference between LENGTH(a.id)=0 and a.id ='' ? (like below answer) ?

Comment: If there is an empty string then length will be zero.It's better to use a length function instead of using a.id="".

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
UPDATE
    jos_jbjobs_jobseeker a
    INNER JOIN jos_users b ON a.email = b.email
SET
    a.user_id = b.id
WHERE a.id ='';
```

If id have null values too then use this-

```
UPDATE
    jos_jbjobs_jobseeker a
    INNER JOIN jos_users b ON a.email = b.email
SET
    a.user_id = b.id
WHERE a.id is null or a.id ='';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code **SQL** native it's work for me very well :

```
UPDATE table 
SET field = 'New value'
WHERE field 
IS NULL
OR field = ''
```

Update just **NULL** value or **EMPTY**.